# Installing pymatbridge

Tags: python, matlab, canopy

I'm using the Canopy distribution and when I try to install pymatbridge using 'pip install pymatbridge' I get an error saying that pymatbridge does not work on win32. I've got the 64-bit version of Canopy so I don't understand what that means.

http://arokem.github.io/python-matlab-bridge/

```
Downloading/unpacking pymatbridge
  Running setup.py (path:C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\build\pymatbridge\setup.py) egg_info for package pymatbridge
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\build\pymatbridge\setup.py", line 25, in <module>
        raise ValueError("pymatbridge does not work on win32")
    ValueError: pymatbridge does not work on win32
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\build\pymatbridge\setup.py", line 25, in <module>

    raise ValueError("pymatbridge does not work on win32")

ValueError: pymatbridge does not work on win32

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\build\pymatbridge
Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\user\pip\pip.log
```

Answer (score 2):

I am the developer of this software. This should work now (since version 0.4), but I don't have a Windows machine to test this one. I have had help from Windows users in developing the patches to make this Windows-functional. Though, I am not always able to solve issues, I am happy to receive suggestions/complaints/praise through our github page:

https://github.com/arokem/python-matlab-bridge/issues

Answer (score 1):

"Win32" in this context means Windows 32- or 64-bit, as distinct from Cygwin.

The developer of pymatbridge introduced this explicit restriction in May 2014:
https://github.com/arokem/python-matlab-bridge/commit/a6fd3cc3adf5ef2b5e3d9b83a8050d783c76d48f

I don't know why. Perhaps, like many small developers, he found the idiosyncrasies of Windows frustrating, and did not have the time to handle them, at least for now. ***[EDIT: See package developer comment below; this restriction was not intentional and has been removed.]***

Is it an option for you to run Matlab in a Linux VM on your Windows machine, or directly on Linux or Mac, in order to use this package?

Comment: Running Matlab in a VM is possible but a bit inconvenient. I'm a bit confused as there does seem to be [discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23716426/installing-pymatbridge-on-windows) of Windows support for the package.

Comment: I suggest that you contact the package developer for clarification. As I mentioned, based on the package source code, this restriction was only introduced in May.

Comment: That was a mistake, that did not get corrected until very recently. Hopefully it works now?